# Fotify scan with visual studio 2005 fails

Tags: visual-studio-2005, fortify

I am trying to scan the C/C++/COM code with fortify 360 (SCA) through visual studio 2005 interface.

The compilation goes through fine. But, fortify scan fails with warning " scan failed: value does not fall under within range".

Please let me know how can we resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your solution's build configuration, you need to set the target architecture to "Any CPU".

If that doesn't solve the problem, you need to contact Fortify Technical Support.